# dotnet ef - The application to execute does not exist C:\Users\

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to use .NET Core Entity Framework. But I couldn't due to an error:

```
dotnet ef
The application to execute does not exist: 
'C:\Users\Curso\.dotnet\tools\.store\dotnet-ef\2.1.14-servicing-32113\dotnet-ef\2.1.14-servicing-32113\tools\netcoreapp2.1\any\dotnet-ef.dll'.
```

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

[image: Error Message Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the dotnet-ef tool, ideally globally so you can run it from anywhere. You can run this from cmd or Powershell terminal or any terminal you are using:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```